# Assigning and using variables based on If condition in Reactive function of R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have written some lines of code in R Shiny and would like to use variables `a` (surface area) and `v` (volume) which are numeric vectors containing 9 values. These variables are calculated using a constant size vector `d`. An if condition determines which formula to execute based on user selection of particle shape from a dropdown menu. The variables `a` and `v` are used in the subsequent steps to create a dataframe, a plot, and a graph.

I am facing 2 problems with my code currently.

1. The variables `a` and `v` are not being calculated which is resulting in an error in the later steps because I am not able to create dataframes which use `a` and `v`.
2. The dataframes I have coded within the `reactive()` function, which are intended to be variable as the values will change based on user selection, are not being created and I cannot figure out why.

Below is the code. I am fairly new to R so any help would be highly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

#UI:
ui <- 
fluidPage(
    navbarPage(
        "TMC Calculator",
        tabPanel(
            "About",
            fluidPage()
        ),
        tabPanel(
            "Contact",
            fluidPage()
        ),
        selectInput("MP_type","Select the type of microplastic",
                    choices=c("High Density Polyethylene" = "HDPE","Polycarbonate" = "PC",
                              "Polyethylene" = "PE","Polyethylene Terephthalate" = "PET",
                              "Polystyrene" = "PS","Polyvinylchloride" = "PVC")),
        selectInput("MP_shape","Select the shape of microplastic",
                    choices=c("Long cylinder","Short cylinder","Sphere",
                              "Oblate spheroid (e=0.2)","Oblate spheroid (e=0.9)")),
        sliderInput("MP_size", "Select the size of microplastic: ",
                    min = 1, 
                    max = 5000, 
                    value = 100, 
                    step = 1),
        textInput("Contaminant", "Enter the contaminant of concern", "Antimony"),
        textInput("AC", "Enter the contaminant adsorption capacity (mg/g)")
        
    ),
    plotOutput("TMC_curve")
)



#SERVER:

#Densities of microplastics
Microplastics_type <- data.frame(Microplastic = c("Polyethylene","Polypropylene","Polystyrene",
                                                  "Polyethylene Terephthalate","Polycarbonate",
                                                  "Polyvinylchloride","High Density Polyethylene"),
                                 Unit_volume = c(1.16, 1.18, 0.93, 0.73, 0.81, 0.72, 1.03))

#Contaminants and their corresponding minimum health endpoint parameters and adsorption capacities
Contaminant <- data.frame("Contaminant"= c("Aluminum","Antimony","Arsenic","BPA","Bromine",
                                           "Cadmium","Chromium","Manganese","Mercury","Propanolol",
                                           "Sulfamethoxazole"),
                          "AC_la" = c(0.375,27.8,1.92,0.19,13,0.00014,0.000454,0.13,
                                      0.00125,0.133,0.087),
                          "G" = c(2.9,0.004,0.003,0.00006,0.01,0.005,0.03,0.12,0.002,0.0005,0.02))

#Defining functions for surface area and volume of shapes (sphere, long & short cylinders and oblate spheroids (e = 0.2 and 0.9))
SPa <- function(d){4*pi*(d/2)^2}
SPv <- function(d){(4/3)*pi*(d/2)^3}
LCa <- function(d){10.5*pi*d^2}
LCv <- function(d){pi*(d/2)^2*(10*d)}
SCa <- function(d){0.6*pi*d^2}
SCv <- function(d){pi*(d/2)^2*(0.1*d)}
OSa <- function(d,e){2*pi*(d/2)^2 + (pi/e)*log((1+e)/(1-e))*((d/2)*(1-e^2)^0.5)^2}
OSv <- function(d,e){(pi/6)*d^3*sqrt(1-e^2)}



function(input, output, session){
    
    d <- c(1, 10, 20, 50, 100, 150, 300, 500, 750)
    
    a <- reactive({
        
        
        if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Sphere"){
            SPa(d)
            
        } else if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Long Cylinder"){
            LCa(d)
            
        } else if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Short Cylinder"){
            SCa(d)
            
        } else if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Oblate Spheroid (e=0.2)"){
            OSa(d, 0.2)
            
        } else if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Oblate Spheroid (e=0.9)"){
            OSa(d, 0.9)
            
        }
    })
    
    v <- reactive ({
        
        
        if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Sphere"){
            
            SPv(d)
        } else if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Long Cylinder"){
            
            LCv(d)
        } else if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Short Cylinder"){
            
            SCv(d)
        } else if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Oblate Spheroid (e=0.2)"){
            
            OSv(d, 0.2)
        } else if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Oblate Spheroid (e=0.9)"){
            
            OSv(d, 0.9)
        }  
        
        Microplastics_type_now <- Microplastics_type %>%
            filter (Microplastic == input$MP_type ) 
        
        TSA <- (1/(Microplastics_type_now$Unit_volume * v) * a)
        
        
        Contaminant_now <- Contaminant %>%
            filter (Contaminant == as.character(input$Contaminant) ) 
        
        TMC <- Contaminant_now$G/(a*((Contaminant_now$AC_la/TSA)))
        
        TMC_curve <- data.frame("TMC" = TMC, "Size" = d)
    })
    
    
    output$TMC_curve <- renderPlot({
        
        ggplot(TMC_curve, aes(x = Size, y = TMC))+
            geom_point()+
            theme_bw()+
            scale_y_log10()
        
    })
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to consider:

1. `a` and `v` are reactive values and they must be called like a function, for example `a()`.
2. `v` is called inside the reactive defining `v`, and because there's no object declared in any environment with that name that would result in an error or in case that it exists it won't have the desired value.
3. The vector of choices defined in the second `selectInput` does not match the ones inside the if statements. (be ware of case sensitiveness)

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

Microplastics_type <- data.frame(Microplastic = c("Polyethylene","Polypropylene","Polystyrene",
                                                  "Polyethylene Terephthalate","Polycarbonate",
                                                  "Polyvinylchloride","High Density Polyethylene"),
                                 Unit_volume = c(1.16, 1.18, 0.93, 0.73, 0.81, 0.72, 1.03))

#Contaminants and their corresponding minimum health endpoint parameters and adsorption capacities
Contaminant <- data.frame("Contaminant"= c("Aluminum","Antimony","Arsenic","BPA","Bromine",
                                           "Cadmium","Chromium","Manganese","Mercury","Propanolol",
                                           "Sulfamethoxazole"),
                          "AC_la" = c(0.375,27.8,1.92,0.19,13,0.00014,0.000454,0.13,
                                      0.00125,0.133,0.087),
                          "G" = c(2.9,0.004,0.003,0.00006,0.01,0.005,0.03,0.12,0.002,0.0005,0.02))

#Defining functions for surface area and volume of shapes (sphere, long & short cylinders and oblate spheroids (e = 0.2 and 0.9))
SPa <- function(d){4*pi*(d/2)^2}
SPv <- function(d){(4/3)*pi*(d/2)^3}
LCa <- function(d){10.5*pi*d^2}
LCv <- function(d){pi*(d/2)^2*(10*d)}
SCa <- function(d){0.6*pi*d^2}
SCv <- function(d){pi*(d/2)^2*(0.1*d)}
OSa <- function(d,e){2*pi*(d/2)^2 + (pi/e)*log((1+e)/(1-e))*((d/2)*(1-e^2)^0.5)^2}
OSv <- function(d,e){(pi/6)*d^3*sqrt(1-e^2)}


ui <- fluidPage(
    navbarPage(
        "TMC Calculator",
        tabPanel(
            "About",
            fluidPage(
                
                
            )
        ),
        tabPanel(
            "Contact",
            fluidPage(
                
            )
            
        ),
        
        
        
        selectInput("MP_type","Select the type of microplastic",
                    choices = unique(Microplastics_type$Microplastic)),
        
        selectInput("MP_shape","Select the shape of microplastic",
                    choices=c("Long Cylinder","Short Cylinder","Sphere",
                              "Oblate Spheroid (e=0.2)","Oblate Spheroid (e=0.9)")),
        
        sliderInput("MP_size", "Select the size of microplastic: ",
                    min = 1, 
                    max = 5000, 
                    value = 100, 
                    step = 1),
        
        selectInput("Contaminant", "Enter the contaminant of concern",choices = unique(Contaminant$Contaminant), "Antimony"),
        
        textInput("AC", "Enter the contaminant adsorption capacity (mg/g)")
        
        
        
        
        
    ),
    plotOutput("TMC_curve")
) 


server <- function(input, output, session) {

    
    
    
    
        
        d <- c(1, 10, 20, 50, 100, 150, 300, 500, 750)
        
        a <- reactive({
            
            
            if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Sphere"){
                SPa(d)
                
            } else if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Long Cylinder"){
                LCa(d)
                
            } else if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Short Cylinder"){
                SCa(d)
                
            } else if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Oblate Spheroid (e=0.2)"){
                OSa(d, 0.2)
                
            } else if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Oblate Spheroid (e=0.9)"){
                OSa(d, 0.9)
                
            }
        })
        
        v <- reactive ({
            
            
            if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Sphere"){
                
                SPv(d)
            } else if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Long Cylinder"){
                
                LCv(d)
            } else if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Short Cylinder"){
                
                SCv(d)
            } else if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Oblate Spheroid (e=0.2)"){
                
                OSv(d, 0.2)
            } else if (as.character(input$MP_shape) == "Oblate Spheroid (e=0.9)"){
                
                OSv(d, 0.9)
            } })  
            
        TMC_curve_df <- reactive({
            print(a())
            print(v())
            
            
            Microplastics_type_now <- Microplastics_type %>%
                filter (Microplastic == input$MP_type ) 
            
            TSA <- (1/(Microplastics_type_now$Unit_volume * v()) * a())
            
            
            Contaminant_now <- Contaminant %>%
                filter (Contaminant == as.character(input$Contaminant) ) 
            
            TMC <- Contaminant_now$G/(a()*((Contaminant_now$AC_la/TSA)))
            
            print(TMC)
            
            TMC_curve <- data.frame("TMC" = TMC, "Size" = d)
        })
        
        
        output$TMC_curve <- renderPlot({
            
            ggplot(TMC_curve_df(), aes(x = Size, y = TMC))+
                geom_point()+
                theme_bw()+
                scale_y_log10()
            
        })
        
    }


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Ok now my code seems to work! Thanks for the help!